# Word search from string in python and providing output into CSV column

Tags: python-3.x, text-mining

**A program that row-wise checks strings if it contains from the list of words and writes 1/0 in the next column named "Result"**

I am looking for filtering text messages containing words like 'PNR' and Airport code (like 'LHR','JFK' etc.)

```
word=['JFK','LHR','DXB']

String=['London airport is LGW','Dubai airport is DXB','My flight is from JFK']

if set(word).intersection(string.split()):
    print("Found One")
```

Check this link for summary https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGid6.jpg
I have 1 million row in a CSV file having text messages.

How can I produce a simple boolean output in the next column with 0 or 1 depending upon message contains any of the words from Set of words.

I am not an advanced programmer, I am working with python and has basic knowledge of programming.
I have done simple extraction from strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to solve your problem. Here's a solution with regular expressions. All airport codes from `word` are joined into a pattern that matches any of the codes as words:

```
import re
pattern = '\\b(' + '|'.join(word) + ')\\b'
#'\\b(JFK|LHR|DXB)\\b'
matches = [1 if re.search(pattern, s) else 0 for s in String]
#[0, 1, 1]
```

You can make your original approach with splitting work, too, but if a code is immediately followed by a period then you will get a false negative.

```
matches = [1 if word_set & set(s.split()) else 0 for s in String]
#[0, 1, 1]
```

That can be fixed by switching from `split()` to `nltk.word_tokenize()`:

```
from nltk import word_tokenize as tokens
word_set = set(word)
matches = [1 if word_set & set(tokens(s)) else 0 for s in String]
#[0, 1, 1]
```

The NLTK-based solution is *much* (x50) slower than the re-based solution. The split-based solution is the fastest, but the least accurate.

Comment: How can i export the result directly to a new column in csv.?  https://imgur.com/0JESYAy.jpg  Check  If i have imported a CSV file and running the code on that.